# How to replace a variable with a variable from preceding column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe like this:

| Family | Genus | Species |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gemmatimonadaceae | Roseisolibacter | Roseisolibacter_agri |
| Bacillaceae | Bacillus | NA |
| Blastocatellaceae | NA | NA |

And I would like to modify it as follow:

| Family | Genus | Species |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gemmatimonadaceae | Roseisolibacter | Roseisolibacter_agri |
| Bacillaceae | Bacillus | Unclassified Bacillus |
| Blastocatellaceae | Unclassified Blastocallaceae | Unclassified Blastocallaceae |

I was trying to do this:

```
 replace_na(
  list(Genus = paste("Unclassified",  Family),
       Species = paste("Unclassified",  Genus)))
```

or using

```
 replace_na(
  list(Genus = paste("Unclassified",  vars(Family)),
       Species = paste("Unclassified",  vars(Genus))))
```

But in both cases I end up with "Unclassified Genus" or "Unclassified ~Genus".

How can I make it inherit from the previous known variable?

I thought also of using `fill()` but it works for tidy data only. Naturally I could transpose the data.frame but there must be a more elegant/simple solution!

Comment: "I could transpose the data.frame but there must be a more elegant/simple solution!": some would say that the tidy solution *is* the elegant solution! ;=)  But here, because you're using data from the same row, I think your current format is the one to use.

Comment: I would like to have it tidy, but the main package I am using for the analyses is phyloseq and this dataframe is imported row-wise :|

Comment: taxonomyTable-class {phyloseq} R Documentation
An S4 class that holds taxonomic classification data as a character matrix.
Description
Row indices represent taxa, columns represent taxonomic classifiers.

Comment: Ah, how often we are constrained by the shortsightedness of others!

Comment: I'm sure this is duplicate of a recently asked question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `mutate` & `coalesce`?

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df = data.frame(
    Family = c('Gemmatimonadaceae', 'Bacillaceae', 'Blastocatellaceae'),
    Genus = c('Roseisolibacter', 'Bacillus', NA),
    Species = c('Roseisolibacter_agri', NA, NA))

df %>%  
    mutate(Genus = coalesce(Genus, paste('Unclassified', Family)),
           Species = coalesce(Species, 
                              if_else(grepl('^Unclassified', Genus),
                                      Genus, paste('Unclassified', Genus))))
#>              Family                          Genus
#> 1 Gemmatimonadaceae                Roseisolibacter
#> 2       Bacillaceae                       Bacillus
#> 3 Blastocatellaceae Unclassified Blastocatellaceae
#>                          Species
#> 1           Roseisolibacter_agri
#> 2          Unclassified Bacillus
#> 3 Unclassified Blastocatellaceae
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I had forgotten about `coalesce`.  Good answer.

Comment: You want `dplyr`, not `tidyr`. As written, your code doubled up "Unclassified". I made edits to your answer. (I also made it easier to read the data on screen.)

Answer (score 0):

I think `replace_na()` isn't going to give you what you want because of the logic you need to apply to rows with missing `Species`: exactly how they are unclassified depends on whether or not `Genus` is missing.

This seems to give you what you want:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    MissingGenus=is.na(Genus),
    Genus=ifelse(MissingGenus, paste(Family, "Unclassified"), Genus),
    Species=ifelse(
             is.na(Species), 
             ifelse(
               MissingGenus, 
               paste(Family, "Unclassified"), 
               paste(Genus, "Unclassified")
             ), 
             Species)
  ) %>% 
  select(-MissingGenus)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Family            Genus                          Species                       
  <chr>             <chr>                          <chr>                         
1 Gemmatimonadaceae Roseisolibacter                Roseisolibacter_agri          
2 Bacillaceae       Bacillus                       Bacillus Unclassified         
3 Blastocatellaceae Blastocatellaceae Unclassified Blastocatellaceae Unclassified
```

A small request: next time, please `dput()` your example data rather than posting images or tables.  It makes testing a solution much easier.